Prestashop 1.7: display categories list in tpl file
I want to display a list of categories in the tpl file of the 404 page.
The categories to be shown are accessible in this array:
    $categories Array (5)
  0 => Array (4)
    id_category => "720"
    name => "brakes"
    link_rewrite => "brakes"
    id_shop => "7"
  1 => Array (4)
    id_category => "721"
    name => "tyres"
    link_rewrite => "tyres"
    id_shop => "7"
  2 => Array (4)
    id_category => "722"
    name => "bumpers"
    link_rewrite => "bumpers"
    id_shop => "7"
  3 => Array (4)
    id_category => "723"
    name => "interiors"
    link_rewrite => "interiors"
    id_shop => "7"
  4 => Array (4)
    id_category => "724"
    name => "accessories"
    link_rewrite => "accessories"
    id_shop => "7"

In the tpl I have added this code:
<ul>
    {foreach from='$categories' item='category'}
        <li>{$category.name}</li>
    {/foreach}
</ul>

I don't understand why the names of the categories are not displayed (I assumed that the foreach loop should display the names of the categories).
Thank you for the help.

You must remove the quotation marks around $categories otherwise you are searching in a string instead of your array.
<ul>
    {foreach from=$categories item=category}
        <li>{$category.name}</li>
    {/foreach}
</ul>

Edit: You can also remove the quotation marks around category in item=category which is not needed, but recommended as a good practice.
If you have any doubts you can also read Smarty docs here: https://www.smarty.net/

Hi Paul, thank you for the help and for the explanation. Removing the quotation marks indeed solved the issue. Also removing the quotation marks from "item=category" is needed? What is the best practice?

Hi, yes, you can and should. I have edited my answer with more details
